# Converting Pandas groupby to a dataframe having columns with boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

My input data is this-

```
    "Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Jake", "Jake", "Steve" , "Bob"] , 
    "City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"],
    "CityID" : ["1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2"]
 } )
```

Which when printed appears as this:

```
   City         Name  CityID
0   Seattle    Alice       1
1   Seattle      Bob       1
2  Portland     Jake       2 
3   Seattle     Jake       1
4   Seattle    Steve       1
5  Portland      Bob       2
```

I am trying to get something like this -

```
       City CityID  Alice   Bob  Jake  Steve
0   Seattle      1   True  True  True   True
1  Portland      2  False  True  True  False
```

I am not sure how to get here.
I did try the groupby function

```
df.groupby(['City','CityID', 'Name']).first()
```

which got me to this-

```
    City    CityID     Name
 Seattle         1    Alice
                        Bob
                       Jake   
Portland         2      Bob
                       Jake
                      Steve
```

I am not sure how to proceed after this, any hints would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `dtype=bool` parameter with unique values in `MultiIndex` by `max`:

```
df = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['City','CityID'])['Name'], dtype=bool)
        .max(level=[0,1])
        .reset_index())
print (df)
       City CityID  Alice   Bob  Jake  Steve
0   Seattle      1   True  True  True   True
1  Portland      2  False  True  True  False
```

---

If need `groupby` solution create new column filled by `True` with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and last convert `MultiIndex` to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) is for remove column name `a`:

```
df = (df.assign(a=True)
        .groupby(['City','CityID', 'Name'], sort=False)['a']
        .first()
        .unstack(fill_value=False)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
       City CityID  Alice   Bob  Jake  Steve
0   Seattle      1   True  True  True   True
1  Portland      2  False  True  True  False
```